# Unity2d Shoot Ball From Cannon at Z Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I have the cannon attached to a hinge2d.
I move it by the Z rotation.

```
    float offset = Mathf.Abs(gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.z);

    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
            gun.transform.rotation, 
            Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, minClamp + offset), 
            rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        gun.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
            gun.transform.rotation, 
            Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, maxClamp + offset),
            rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

This code has an offset for Z-rotation of any object the the cannon is mounted on.

When the cannon is fully up, I have it constrained to Z = 30.

When the cannon is fully down, I have it constrained to Z = -60.

What I'm trying to do is shoot the cannon ball out and up based on where the cannon is pointing.

I have tried a few different things, all of which didn't work.

```
private void ShootBullet()
{
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, gunTip.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    var rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    //setting rotation of bullet to have same rotation of cannon stem
    bullet.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
        gun.transform.eulerAngles.x,
        gun.transform.eulerAngles.y,
        gun.transform.eulerAngles.z + Mathf.Abs(gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.z));



    //this is my issue right now, I dont know how to apply the correct force to the Y direction based on the Z(angle) of my cannon.
    rb.AddForce(new Vector3( bulletSpeed, ?, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your issue? The rotation of the bullet or the move direction? Be a bit careful with your phrases since `move` is done vis the position, not the rotation ;)

Comment: @derHugo The rotation is not my issue. I'm not sure how to calculate the angle to make the cannon ball looks realistic in terms of physics. For instance, right now if I apply more force to X than Y it goes right further and does not look natural. The X force is not my issue, its knowing what my Y force is suppose to be based on the angle of my cannon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some code snippet which may help you.

```cs
void Launch() {
    GameObject clone = Instantiate (projectile, shootLocation, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    Rigidbody2D clonerb = clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    clonerb.AddRelativeForce (
        transform.TransformDirection(new Vector2( 
            (Mathf.Cos (transform.rotation.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * speed),
            (Mathf.Sin (transform.rotation.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * speed) )
        ),
        ForceMode2D.Impulse
    );
}
```

Source: [1](https://forum.unity.com/threads/shooting-based-on-the-rotation-of-a-cannon.361398/)

Further more an Setup that I created just now and worked is following:

```
public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Bullet;
    public Transform ShootPoint;

    public float bulletSpeed = 10.0f;


    void Start() {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            if(!Bullet)
                return;
            GameObject clone = Instantiate(Bullet, ShootPoint.position, ShootPoint.rotation);
            Rigidbody2D rb2d = clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb2d.AddRelativeForce(Vector2.right * bulletSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have a lot of redundancies there ... why use `transform.TransformDirection` if using `AddRelativeForce` anyway? And why use relative vector at all if you are already using the global `z` rotation?

Comment: I was quiet confused of this too and had no time to try yet. I just found that and though it may help as an input. I give you right it seems kinda redundant.

Comment: @AtLeastVision I ended up having to use your first answer because I'm using a hinge2d which is throwing off the angle. The second answer did not work for me I "Think" because of the hinge joint for my rotation. transform.TransformDirection converts to world coords, this may be why it works using it.

Comment: @exceptionsAreBad ah yeah that does indeed make sense but i guess with some changes the 2nd would work to I jsut dont have your setup. But as long as the first one does work thats good :D

Answer (score 0):

You could rather simply use [`AddRelativeForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddRelativeForce.html)

> Adds a force to the rigidbody2D relative to its coordinate system.

which takes the orientation of the object into account:

```
// You should also simply set the rotation vis the Rigidbody2D component
rb.rotation = gunTip.transform.eulerAngles.z;
rb.AddRelstiveForce(Vector2.right * bulletSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce what I'm looking for. No matter the angle of the cannon, the ball follows the same path when shooting. Vector3.right is also only adding force in the X direction.

Comment: I would think of trying like Vector3.up and so on to. It could be that you have your object rotatet weired.

Comment: @exceptionsAreBad Yes but if you read the API it is using the local "right" direction meaning it uses the rotated direction

Comment: ye but it oculd be that he screwed up his canon which may be rotated like 90° wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being what I needed. Thanks @At Least Vision

```
private void ShootBullet()
{
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, gunTip.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    var rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    bullet.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(gun.transform.eulerAngles.x, gun.transform.eulerAngles.y, gun.transform.eulerAngles.z);

    rb.AddRelativeForce(
    bullet.transform.TransformDirection(new Vector2(
        (Mathf.Cos(bullet.transform.rotation.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * bulletSpeed),
        (Mathf.Sin(bullet.transform.rotation.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * bulletSpeed))
    ),
    ForceMode2D.Impulse
);

}
```

Comment: I am happy it does work. I have also posted another solution I just used. Btw if you use stretched bullets you may need to add a script to them so they always look at the direction they are flying onto cuz it may look weired other way

Comment: Oh and btw you can choose one of the answers here as the one that answeres you question so the question is "closed" (People will know you have solved it already without openening the post)